# Are there any strains of Judaism that think Islam is not a heresy?

Tags: gentiles, islam

Are there any sects of  Judaism that think Islam is not a heresy for goyim? If yes would like to know more about such a sect.

Comment: the Sabbatians / Donmeh

Comment: Not all Muslims reject the Torah and Talmud, so why should it be? https://www.judaism-islam.com/islam-teaches-torah-is-corrupted-tahrif-but-what-does-that-mean/   https://www.judaism-islam.com/was-abraham-commanded-to-sacrifice-isaac-or-ishmael/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A little known 12th century Yemenite rabbi, Natanel Al-Fayyumi, once suggested that not only did Allah SWT establish an eternal covenant with Moses AS and Banu Yisrael, but He may have also established a covenant with Muhammad SAW and the Muslims. However, academic consensus says that he was forced to write this under duress."<sup>1</sup>

1. The Bustan al-Ukul, by Nathanael ibn al-Fayyumi, edited and
   translated by David Levine, Columbia University Oriental Studies
   Vol. VI, p. 105
   (https://www.judaism-islam.com/jewish-view-of-islam/)

The webpage goes on to describe how all the 7 Noahide laws are mentioned in the Koran. If you can find which rabbi / sect  is associated with this website, you may have your answer.

Comment: That website is very clearly run by Muslims.

Comment: @יהושעק The Alsadiqin Institute is an association of Muslim and Rabbinic scholars of history and jurisprudence. Founder and Director: Rabbi Ben Abrahamson. His book has haskama from Rabbi Yoel Schwartz of Yeshivat Dvar Yerushalayim and Sheikh Dr. Hoja Ramzy of Oxford U